# Ignoring superscript in title tags

Tags: php, html, css, superscript

I work on a database driven website.  Most pages' titles are the names of partners we have, and served from a database using php.

For example one page might be called "Experian".  The problem is that some of the values for partner names don't work because the values are things like

```
  $partnername22 = Discover<sup>tm</sup> Magazine
```

I can't use this for a title because superscript can't show up in a title, and I can't change the value because many other things depend on it.  Is there a trick I can pull to make the browser ignore the superscript tags if they are in the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For:

```
<title><?php echo $offer22name ?>is a magazine</title>
```

change to:

```
<title><?php echo preg_replace('|<sup>(.*?)</sup>|', '($1)', $offer22name) ?> is a magazine</title>
```

But like Bryan mentioned, you should use PHP's strip_tags() in this scenario.  So:

```
<title><?php echo strip_tags($offer22name) ?> is a magazine</title>
```

Comment: In case you miss the other comment I made, The regexp I used would result in: Discover(tm) Magazine.

Answer (score 2):

It would be very simple (and probably advisable) to use PHP's strip_tags() command to remove all of the html from your string before posting it as a title.

Answer (score 2):

```
<title><?PHP echo str_replace('<sup>tm</sup>', '&trade;', $offer22name); ?> is a magazine</title>
```

Or, more safer:

```
<title><?PHP echo strip_tags(str_replace('<sup>tm</sup>', '&trade;', $offer22name)); ?> is a magazine</title>
```

Or, catching more cases (not sure on this one exactly):

```
<title><?PHP echo strip_tags(preg_replace('/<sup.*?>\s+[Tt][Mm]\s*</(sup|)>', '&trade;', $offer22name)); ?> is a magazine</title>
```

You can replace the `'&trade;'` with `'&#8482;'`, `'&#x2122;'`, or '™' if you wish (but make sure encodings match for the last one), depending on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Not AFAIK, but if you're already scripting out a string from the DB, why can't you script out the same string regex replacing tags (or tag pairs, as you wish) with empty strings?

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no.

Ideally you would do `$partnername22 = strip_tags('Discover<sup>tm</sup> Magazine');` (or something fancier), but if you can't to that then I'm afraid you're stuck with a Javascript solution.

Something like:

```
window.title = window.title.replace(/<sup.*?</sup>/, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expression in PHP that will replace <sup>text</sup> with (text):

```
$title = preg_replace('|<sup>(.*?)</sup>|', '\($1\)', $title);
```

It would be similar to do this in javascript.

Comment: In response to Bryan (I can't respond to his for lack of points) I did mean to include the parans so that the result has something distinguishing the text.  But the slashes should be removed.  So the result looks like:

Discover(tm) Magazine

It wouldn't look right if it was:

Discovertm Magazine

Comment: Ah cool, thanks for clarifying. I didn't understand what you had been trying to do there. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Mike, I think you meant this:

```
$title = preg_replace('|<sup>(.*?)</sup>|', '$1', $title);
```

The way you had it before prints some slashes and parenthesis around the tagged word. Right?

pg, you could also just do

```
$title = preg_replace('|<sup>(.*?)</sup>|', '', $title);
```

if you wanted to completely remove the superscripted info from the title.

Comment: I don't understand the usage here.  How do I use this $title value to remove the supercripted text?  

now the text of the document is:
     <title><?php echo $offer22name ?>is a magazine</title> 

Where do I put the $title value and what do I do with it to make it take out everything in the tags?

Comment: @pg, bryan meant that $partnername22 == $title.  He reworded it in his post to make it clearer that you are editing the Web page's title, and not the partner's name.

Answer (score 0):

How about the simple expedient of some CSS?

```
h2.title sub, h2.title sup { vertical-align: baseline; font-size:100%; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use character encoding instead of the  tag, e.g.  `&trade;`, `&#153;`